# Implementing OR Condition using Parse Android SDK?

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I am new to [Parse](https://parse.com/) and i am working on a Project that uses Android PARSE Sdk so i was wondering on how can i make a where query with or condition using the android sdk.

I want to make a query like this [Psuedo code]

```
Select * from employ where employId is ("1","2","3")
```

I found [this](https://parse.com/questions/how-to-achieve-or-condition-in-query) on parse documentation, i don't know if it helps or not.

**Edit:**

This is what i found on PARSE but its not working

```
String[] id= {"1","2","3"};
query.whereContainedIn("employId ", Arrays.asList(id));
```

It returns me an empty list but if i query them one by one i get result... Can anyone tell me whats wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution and i must say its pretty lame of [PARSE](https://parse.com) to not mention this anywhere in there documentation.

The problem was that the values that i was using in`whereContainedIn` method were of type String  **but in reality they were pointers to another table's row**.
I was trying to get the values using only there **ids[as it is displayed on parse]** but instead i had to pass the **whole object** in order to retrieve them. That was the reason on why it was returning empty list.

The thing is Even though it displays IDs [pointer to object in a table] we cant search using only ID's instead we have to use complete Parse objects if we want to search a table based on Specific Object.

Comment: You can create a pointer object using just the ID using `ParseObject.createWithoutData("ClassNameHere", "objectIdHere")` as per the docs here: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-pointers

Answer (score 3):

You can use whereContainedIn to select specific rows. See this post you can get more ideas. https://www.parse.com/questions/different-arrays-and-wherecontainedin-for-android.

```
List<String> employId = new ArrayList<String>();
employId.add("1"); employId.add("2"); employId.add("2");
query.whereContainedIn("employId", employId);
```

If you are still not clear. check this https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries

Comment: Its not working. Can you write the exact query or code ?

Comment: It gives error it doesn't even compile. it says "The method whereContainedIn(String, Collection<? extends Object>) in the type ParseQuery<ParseObject> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String[])"

Comment: bro i am doing this but its returning no records even though there are records. Before i was querying using separate values in the list and it was returning records but in this way its not returning any records

Comment: Try with integer instead of string for employ id.

Comment: I Solved it.Check my answer. Silly Parse documentation